# string to datetime conversion using System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have the following code to convert string into datetime..

```
string updateDateTime = "1398398552695";

double temp = Double.Parse(updateDateTime);
TimeSpan sp = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(temp);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Add(sp);
updateDateTime = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");//final date time

string tt = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
DateTime output1;
DateTime.TryParseExact(tt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out output1);

DateTime output2 = DateTime.ParseExact(tt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dt);
Console.WriteLine(tt);
Console.WriteLine(output1);
Console.WriteLine(output2);
```

If we see the output it will be something like this..

```
25/04/2014 04:02:32//dt
2014-04-25 04:02:32//tt
25/04/2014 04:02:32//output1
25/04/2014 04:02:32//output2
```

the problem is if we see output1 and output2 it is actually not giving result in yyyy-MM-dd format and I need value in this  format and in datetime type only coz in in database(MySQL) the field is in DateTime Format.
So, i want the output in  2014-04-25 04:02:32 format but it is string and I need to convert it to datetime.

Note : There are many questions related to this problem here in stackoverflow but my reputation is not enough to comment on them so I had to create this new question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datetime is appearing this way because in your `Region Settings` in `Control Panel` Date and Time format is set this way.

Please go to **Control Panel** and Select **Region** and in Formats tab Select correct value or else go to **Additional Settings** to customize your Date and Time format.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this problem is hidden in your code

just after this code

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(tt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out output1);
```

add

```
string od1 = output1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
```

I hope this will help